# Postgresql export result with copy statement including return/newline character

Tags: postgresql

Hi I need to export dynamic query result with return or new line character in copy statement.

```
COPY( SELECT 'SELECT now(); '||E'\n'||' REINDEX TABLE "' || schemaname || '"."' || relname || '";' FROM pg_stat_all_tables ORDER BY n_dead_tup DESC)TO 'E:\scripts\maintenance\reindex.sql';
```

Query itself works fine from the query editor;

```
SELECT 'SELECT now(); '||E'\n'||' REINDEX TABLE "' || schemaname || '"."' || relname || '";' FROM pg_stat_all_tables ORDER BY n_dead_tup DESC
```

when I copy the results from the resultset pane and paste it to the any text editor, I get what I want. But inside the COPY statement, it is not working.

Comment: `SELECT unnest(array['SELECT now();', format('REINDEX TABLE %I.%I;', schemaname, relname)]) FROM pg_stat_all_tables ORDER BY n_dead_tup DESC;` - use it in your `COPY` statement.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `COPY` text format renders a newline character as `\n`.

If you *really* want to write a multi-line SQL script that way, you could do away with the newline, for it is not really necessary.

You can also consider using the [adminpack](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/adminpack.html) functions for writing the file.